# Is there a "well known" example of a constraint satisfaction problem on a 3-element set which is polynomial-time solvable?

Tags: polynomial-time, constraint-satisfaction

I'm basically looking for an example (in maybe graph theory) of a constraint satisfaction problem which has a 3-element set as a domain and the problem is known to be polynomial-time solvable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a graph, it needs to be bipartite. Hence the path of two edges or any subgraph thereof. (Here I am following the convention that graphs have no loops. As David Richerby points out in a comment, graphs with loops also have polynomial-time CSPs (by virtue of triviality).)

A more interesting example is linear algebra over the three-element field: The domain is the set of congruence classes $\bmod 3$ and the constraint relations are given by linear equations.

Comment: The graph case is also decidable in polynomial time if the graph has at least one self-loop.